# Hyperledger Orderer is not working with Kafka - error decoding packet: CRC didn't match

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger

I am trying to launching Hyperledger Fabric Orderer with Kafka. I have four Kafka brokers. I am getting the following error.

```
2018-12-24 16:15:39.795 CST [orderer/consensus/kafka] processMessagesToBlocks -> ERRO 0ec [channel: ordererchannel] Error during consumption: kafka: error while consuming ordererchannel/0: kafka: error decoding packet: CRC didn't match expected 0x0 got 0xe38a6876
2018-12-24 16:15:39.796 CST [orderer/consensus/kafka] processMessagesToBlocks -> WARN 0ed [channel: ordererchannel] Deliver sessions will be dropped if consumption errors continue.
2018-12-24 16:15:41.796 CST [orderer/consensus/kafka/sarama] dispatcher)-fm -> DEBU 0ee consumer/ordererchannel/0 finding new broker
2018-12-24 16:15:41.796 CST [orderer/consensus/kafka/sarama] RefreshMetadata -> DEBU 0ef client/metadata fetching metadata for [ordererchannel] from broker 192.168.1.36:9092
2018-12-24 16:15:41.809 CST [orderer/consensus/kafka/sarama] Open -> DEBU 0f0 ClientID is the default of 'sarama', you should consider setting it to something application-specific.
2018-12-24 16:15:41.809 CST [orderer/consensus/kafka/sarama] subscriptionConsumer -> DEBU 0f1 consumer/broker/3 added subscription to ordererchannel/0
2018-12-24 16:15:41.810 CST [orderer/consensus/kafka] processMessagesToBlocks -> WARN 0f2 [channel: ordererchannel] Consumption will resume.
2018-12-24 16:15:41.816 CST [orderer/consensus/kafka/sarama] withRecover -> DEBU 0f3 Connected to broker at 192.168.1.50:9092 (registered as #3)
2018-12-24 16:15:41.832 CST [orderer/consensus/kafka/sarama] subscriptionConsumer)-fm -> DEBU 0f4 consumer/broker/3 disconnecting due to error processing FetchRequest: kafka: error decoding packet: CRC didn't match expected 0x0 got 0xe38a6876
2018-12-24 16:15:41.833 CST [orderer/consensus/kafka/sarama] abort -> DEBU 0f5 Closed connection to broker 192.168.1.50:9092
```

I am using Kafka 2.0 and hyperledger fabirc 1.3.0.

Comment: Problem solved by downgrading kafka version.

Comment: which kafka version now you're using?